# Restrict access in firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, restriction

I am making a web app using firebase. I was looking into restricting access to certain pages unless there's a subscription. When I looked through the docs all I found was that I could do transactions with stripe and it only applied on signing in and up not restricting pages.

After searching on the internet, I didn't find a viable solution, but three ideas came up to me I could use (which are either with low working possibility or very lackluster to say the least. (all include using stripe.))

One: I would use a middleware to verify the token I get from stripe and then redirect from there. (but all that comes to my mind how I would identify the redirected page in the middleware. And even if that was probable how much time would that take to make it work(if that even is possible), I have no idea.)

Two: in hosting configurations I could call a function when a rewrite is performed. I thought I could call a make a function that verifies the token from the strip when a restricted page is called. (But then again not only is the function accessible after hosting and can be viewed, I don't know if I can call firebase configurations and functions inside the firebase.json.)

third: this is the most viable but has very bad downsides, is authenticating the strip token from in a regular javascript, and if it fails it would restrict the access to the page. Do the same in the rules so that the database section related to that page. (the downside is that the HTML, CSS, and javascript would all be accessible. Only the database functions relating to them are restricted.

So with all that being said, I couldn't find any viable option I could use. So I was wondering if anyone in here have met the same problem and got a solution or do you have any advice I could use.
Note: I am using firebase's realtime database by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to restrict access to your webpages/app, you should come up with a logic in your backend or frontend (depending on your app structure) where you could store values needed in Firestore or another solution.

In case you would like to restrict access to Firestore, you can achieve that with [Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/rules-conditions).

Comment: Yeah, that seems like the only viable option right now. What I didn't like in this was whatever I do, the code still becomes available for the user. So after I come up with something on my code to restrict them, and that is after I restrict it from the rules, if someone decides to look through the code they would still find the page, although the functions would be restricted by the rules, the code for the restricted page is still open, can't say I like something like this, I thought I could do some verification on the firebase itself not through the code. Thank you for the answer.